Не приходит сообщение в боте (тг)
# keyboards 
    from aiogram.types import  ReplyKeyboardMarkup , KeyboardButton , InlineKeyboardMarkup,InlineKeyboardButton
    
    
    
    main = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[[KeyboardButton(text='Меню')]])
    
    
    
    catalog =  InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text='Подать заявку ', callback_data='Zayvka')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text='О нас', callback_data='About us')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text='Мануалы', callback_data='Manual')]])
    
    
    
    
    
    # handlers 
    from aiogram import F, Router
    from aiogram.types import  Message, CallbackQuery
    from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
    
    import app.keyboards as kb
    
    router=Router()
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @router.message (F.text == 'Меню')
    async def catalog(message:Message):
        await message.answer('Вы открыли меню.', reply_markup=kb.catalog)
    
    
        @router.callback_query(F.data =='Zayvka')
        async def Manual(callback: CallbackQuery):
           await callback.message.answer('12312')
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    #main
    
    import asyncio
    from aiogram import  Bot, Dispatcher
    from app.handlers import router
    
    async def main():
        bot = Bot(token='тут токен')
        dp = Dispatcher()
    
        dp.include_router(router)
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            asyncio.run(main())
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Бот офф')
    
    

Не приходит сообщение от бота по InlineKeyboardButton

Не верная табуляция:
@router.message(F.text == 'Меню')
async def catalog(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Вы открыли меню.', reply_markup=kb.catalog)

    @router.callback_query(F.data == 'Zayvka')
    async def Manual(callback: CallbackQuery):
        await callback.message.answer('12312')

Верная табуляция: (и все будет работать)
@router.message(F.text == 'Меню')
async def catalog(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Вы открыли меню.', reply_markup=kb.catalog)

@router.callback_query(F.data == 'Zayvka')
async def Manual(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.answer('12312')


а что вы изменили ,я просто понять не могу

@owukaw я поменял структуру кода. До этого у вас в функции catalog был callback_query c функцией Manual.

сможете тогда с кое чем помочь?У меня нет кнопки меню хотя код вроде написан
main = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[[KeyboardButton(text='Меню')]])

@owukaw Судя по коду выше, не совсем понятно, где должна находится кнопка "Меню". Вижу только обработчик @router.message(F.text == 'Меню'), в котором есть функция catalog. Т.е. пользователю будет выводится сообщение 'Вы открыли меню.', при вводе слова Меню.

ну кнопка должна быть в тг там где ты пишешь сообщение

@owukaw ну это понятно))))) я имею ввиду при каких обстоятельствах - когда например будет запущен бот /start или там будет какое то главное меню кнопок, из которых будет конкретная кнопка Меню. К примеру если при старте бота нужно это реализовать, то необходимо создать обработчик команд, поместить в нее функцию, в которой будет вызываться меню инлайн кнопок(ки)
